# Why do I get error in executing 2 C files under the same project in Xcode 10.1?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode10.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ew0g.png)I am not able to make two files under a same project in Xcode 10.1. I am able to build and run successfully a single main file in Xcode but when I add another while it gives a linked error as shown in the below image. Please help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQs5I.png)

I am getting this error "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: You can't have two main functions in the same executable.

Comment: Do I need to make a separate project to add another file?

Comment: You can have as many files as you want but only one which contains the main function.

Comment: I am really confused! I don't know what that means ? Can you please explain a little, I am kind of new to Xcode! For eg. If I have written two programs that are mutually exclusive of each other for say, one is a calculator (one file) and the other one is displaying a string (2nd file) , Can't I run them under one project? It would be really great if you can help!

Comment: No you can't. One project produces one executable or library. If you want multiple executables you need to have one project for each.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was really helpful.